# why printing slice using fmt.Println(slice) is different in Golang

Tags: go

code A:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := IntSlice{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

type IntSlice []int
```

output A:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

code B:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := IntSlice{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

type IntSlice []int

func (slice IntSlice) Error() string { return "this is called." }
```

output B:

```
this is called.
```

why the behavior of `fmt.Println(slice)` is different for these two codes( A and B)?
or why `fmt.Println(slice)` calls `slice.Error()` automatically?

Comment: From the Go docs: "4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [documented](https://godoc.org/fmt) as part of the behaviour of `fmt` (emphasis mine):

> Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces. In order of application:
>
> 1. If the operand is a reflect.Value, the operand is replaced by the concrete value that it holds, and printing continues with the next rule.
> 2. If an operand implements the Formatter interface, it will be invoked. Formatter provides fine control of formatting.
> 3. If the %v verb is used with the # flag (%#v) and the operand implements the GoStringer interface, that will be invoked.
>
>    If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
> 4. **If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).**
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
>
> For compound operands such as slices and structs, the format applies to the elements of each operand, recursively, not to the operand as a whole. Thus %q will quote each element of a slice of strings, and %6.2f will control formatting for each element of a floating-point array.

The `fmt` package sees that `slice` implements `error` and prints `value.Error()`, rather than iterating over the slice and applying formatting to each element.

Comment: basically, if you make an struct implements an `Error() string` method it becomes for the existing core libraries an error object, but not for your custom code. The discussion would be : what is the sense of having a Error() string into an IntSlice...